# Rich Textarea Editor for Wordpress Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am trying to create a Rich Textarea Editor in a widget textarea.

I have read the documentation about wp_editor() and even tried to integrate but as they explain it is not possible to use it in draggable items.

I also have tried to integrate the Editor from Black Studio TinyMCE Widget plugin, however even with some recommendations from the plugin developer it doesn't work.

I also have tried to integrate the CLEditor to no avail. It loads, it shows the buttons but the text doesnt appear until I inspect the element, I tried to fix this but I couldn't find a way.

So my question is has someone succesfully integrated a Rich Textarea Editor in a custom Widget?

Comment: According to the documents, you can have a `wp_editor` instance in a draggable item, it just needs to be called from a 'edit_page_form` action. [See here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Notes)

Comment: I have tried to do the following `add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'pre_sized_editor' );
function pre_sized_editor() {
 wp_editor( $instance['description'], $this->get_field_id('description'), array('textarea_name'=>$this->get_field_name('description'),'media_buttons'=>false) );
}`

instead declaring the `<textarea ... ></textarea>`
and still doesn't work in fact page gets a blank error
@cpilko

Comment: Has someone done this?